# c# Script Error "Line3 is a' variable' but is used like a method - Help Understand

Tags: c#, syntax-error

**EDIT -** Thank You Grant & Tim for the previous answer, however it doesn't look like my current code was able to turn the output into decimal form. How can i make the input of the user display as a decimal?

```
Console.WriteLine("*************** Get Mileage***************");
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("Enter the Gas Mileage:");           
line3 = Console.ReadLine();

if (int.TryParse(line3, out val))                       
{
    double mileage = Convert.ToDouble(line3());
    Console.WriteLine("Your car MPG is: " + mileage.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("*************** Program Termination***************");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you. Press any key to terminate the program...");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please only enter a interger, Please Close and try again");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a typo on this line:

```
Convert.ToDouble(line3());
```

By typing `line3()`, it suggests that `line3` is a method you're trying to call.

Remove the extra parentheses:

```
Convert.ToDouble(line3);
```

---

Why are you doing an `int.TryParse` on `line3`, and then on the next line converting it to a `double`?

Just try parsing it as a double to start with, then use that parsed value:

```
double mpg;

if (double.TryParse(line3, out mpg))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your car MPG is: " + mpg);
    ...
```

Comment: Thank You, however it doesn't look like my current code was able to turn the output into decimal form. How can i make the input of the user display as a decimal?